# Should you always use both Redux and REST API?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

When working with React or React Native, common scenario is using **redux-thunk** so you can keep your backend and redux state in sync.

I realized that most of the times, the same pattern is used for all functionalities, where you would call the REST API, and after response, update the Redux state:

example:

```
// ADD ARTICLE
export const addArticle = (article) => {
    type: 'ADD_ARTICLE',
    article
}

export const startAddArticle = (articleData) => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => { 
        ...
       // call api using axios or fetch and dispatch addArticle at the end
    }
}
```

Should you always use this pattern (or Redux at all), and if yes what is the benefit of doing so, instead of just making one class from which you would call your REST API (something similar to DataService in Angular) and not using Redux state at all, since all the information are already stored in database and accessible via backend calls?

Answer (score 1):

Redux is unidirectional data flow, in another word, it is the source of truth on your application. It makes easier to interact with state. Think about, you have a modal component and want to close and open it without passing the props from parent component, you can make this very easily with redux. (Also context api as well but our focus is for now Redux. You can google for more info about context api)

Redux thunk is an middleware of redux to make async calls. It takes your action, makes async call when response returns calls the next chain of redux.  Very simple work flow is like below,

`action -> middleware(redux-thunk) -> reducer -> state -> View`

> Should you always use this pattern (or Redux at all)

You don't have to use this pattern always. For more complicated apps that you want to track also loading state, you can use Redux-Saga as example, you can track loading state also with redux-thunk but it is not very handy as Redux-Saga in my opinion. Saga's uses generator pattern which is great to make multiple calls.

> or Redux at all

If your project is way too small you don't have to use Redux, you might want to look at Mobx. Also some people does not use redux when they are using Apollo Graphql client. But to be honest Redux keeps things simple.

Comment: Yea, I realize the benefit of Redux in state management for things like modal, or any other information which should be easily accessible everywhere. My question is should I also manage state for all entities, and create action creators for all my crud operations, and not just use Redux for some state information like if modal is open, currently logged user etc. (I assume I should since I agree it looks better and more logical, I just want to know the reason we do these kinda redundant storing in both state and backend, and the benefit of keeping state for everything)

Comment: I don't understand exactly what do you mean with ` I just want to know the reason we do these kinda redundant storing in both state and backend`. Actions might seem redundant to you, however they are not if every action is making a different job.

Comment: By redundant I mean, if we have article table for example at the backend database, why do we keep track of articles in Redux state, when it is sufficient to just do crud operations on backend rest api, and not manage articles state in Redux at all

Comment: @nemanjagajic, you are questioning the usage of **state** here instead of Redux if I understand you right. So, answers would be very opinion-based if we tried to explain this. Do you prefer re-fetch all the data whenever you need it in a single component? Or, how do you plan to share this data with all your components? Answers vary and they will be opinion-based.